# How to generate interactive multi page graphics on the web?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I want to create a web application / page that has 2D graphical content and where the user can interactively click on the graphics to interact / modify it there. Allowed languages are PHP and JavaScript, only modern browsers (Firefox and Chrome as well as Android and iOS) necessary.

This is the easy part as it can be done with `<canvas>` or with SVG.

But the problem arises that the result must be printable and the graphics is so big that it will span multiple pages.
The page break must be closely controlled by the program and each page also get some defined frame / background.

What would be the best technique to implement such an application?

A `<canvas>` where the Print-View will use multiple `<canvas>` (content closely controlled by the application) and hope that the browser does the page break exactly between the canvases? Is there a way force the browser to do that?

Or can that be done with SVG?
SVG1.2 has multi page support but that got dropped for SVG2 AFAIK...

(Additional note: if both would be possible, I'd prefer SVG as the content is highly vector orientated and when the user prints into a PDF it would generate a much nicer result)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't try to implement page-breaks yourself. Applications dedicated to graphics can deal with the details needed to format images onto paper. Did you know that you could just get a giant printer and have it all fit onto a single page, for example?

Just produce as big an image as necessary, and, let an offline program do the printing. DPI is a factor, too. You probably want to produce something that's 10000's or more pixels wide/high to get a finely detailed large-scale print. Browsers will probably crash before you can even produce/load/save the data.

Comment: Even after reading your question, I'm not sure what you're searching for, but I'd suggest you start with .PDF. PDF capabilities include: renders to both screen & printable, built-in pagination, allows SVG content.

Comment: @starlocke It is important that I can control the page break as e.g. lines that continue on the next page need special marking and symbols like marking the coordinates on the new page where it is starting again. Cf http://www.fricad.de/Beispiele/Stromlaufplan/SP.gif as being the first Google hit of what I want to create...

Comment: @markE you are right that PDF is the perfect format for the finished result that the user will create. But it's not interactive in such a way that I can use it to let the user modify and work with the content.  
Of course I could use both, a huge graphic (like SVG) for the interactive part and an PDF export to get the correct pagewise printing going. But as that should be a small project I fear the need to create two output streams - one for the interaction in e.g. SVG and one in PDF for export and printing.

Comment: You can use javascript to build pdf's (fEx: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) That way you have the dynamics you need in javascript and the format you need in .pdf. If you use canvas or svg for the dynamic editing, you could overlay a dotted-line where the pages will break (you will know the resolution of your .pdf in pixels so you can place the page-break line at the appropriate pixel position in the editor.